# Quarkus don't build, if there is a parent

Tags: java, maven, kotlin, quarkus

I am currently trying to build a quarkus application. But maven does not build, if there is a parent in the directory.

```
./mvnw compile quarkus:dev
```

This works, if there is no parent.

If I add this to maven:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>..</relativePath>
</parent>
```

it does not build and hangs up at:

```
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:0.15.0:dev (default-cli) @ quarkus ---
```

The full output is:

```
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Detected Maven Version: 3.6.0
[DEBUG] Detected Maven Version (3.6.0)  is allowed in [3.5.3,).
[DEBUG] Using javaTool: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java
```

Did someone had the same issue?

Thanks

Comment: when you add that `parent`, do you really have a parent pom xml file in its parent folder?

Comment: I have one module with parent and I can run submodule. I haven't relativePath element

Comment: Yes, it is in the folder once above.

Comment: Could you create a GitHub issue with a simple reproducer here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues? It might be a bug in our Maven plugin's resolution so let's follow up on GitHub. Thanks!

Comment: I think I found the issue, if there is a parent in the parent with spring dependency, it wont work

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `<relativePath>` of the parent poms hierarchy are valid, as Quarkus resolution is less lenient than usual Maven plugins.

I had an invalid empty `<relativePath></relativePath>` in a parent, which caused Quarkus to hang into an infinite loop (that wasn't stackoverflowing, so no stacktrace unless debugging).